# Automatically Updating Table in R

Tags: r, automation, scheduling

I'm regularly connected to our database, whose data continuously changes. I was wondering if there was a way to run a specific set of lines of code on a regular time interval? For example:

```r
list_table <- as_tibble(mydatabaseconnection %>%
                 tbl("mytable"))

View(list_table , title = "list_table")
```

I run this manually every now and then, but it would be nice to have the table on one of my screens and have it update periodically on its own. So far all I've found are tools that automatically run an entire script and you can only view their output as images or excel files. Any way to do what I outlined above within RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `Sys.sleep()` inside a for loop, e.g.:

```
for (i in 1:24) {
  print(i)
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

In this case, it would look like:

```
for (i in 1:24) {

  list_table <- as_tibble(mydatabaseconnection %>%
                   tbl("mytable"))

  View(list_table , title = "list_table")

  Sys.sleep(5)

}
```